# Launch LibGDX project with Android Studio

Tags: libgdx, android-studio

I've used "setup UI" to generate my LibGDX game projects.
Then I've imported them into Android Studio . It didn't show any errors at first , but when I've tried to run the android project , it gave me strange errors like :

> java: cannot find symbol
>     symbol:   variable super
>     location: class com.yan.waterworld.MainActivity

Here is an image :
[image]

How can it be solved (or worked around) ?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

**Update**:

Since Android Studio 0.8.0 it is now possible to run Java and Android modules.  This will not work by following these instructions (Android studio is based on Intellij).
[Gradle Configuration](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Gradle-and-Intellij-IDEA)

**Old**:

They have forums and notice here: https://code.google.com/p/libgdx/wiki/AndroidStudio

> Using libgdx with Android Studio
>
> At Google I/O 2013, the Android tools
>   team released Android Studio, and IDE based on IntelliJ IDEA, focusing
>   on pure Android development.
>
> Android Studio is sadly unfit for libgdx projects at this time, as it
>   only allows the creation of Android projects. Standard Java projects
>   are not supported, and it is unclear if this will ever become
>   available.
>
> Libgdx's cross-platform nature does not lend itself well to
>   development with Android Studio. This should not be a big hindrance,
>   as libgdx projects don't benefit much from Android Studios
>   capabilities. E.g. the layout preview is irrelevant for libgdx
>   applications, as they don't use native Android UI widgets. The inline
>   documentation support for Android APIs is also not needed for libgdx
>   applications.
>
> However, we'll try to make developing libgdx applications with the new
>   Android Gradle build system possible in the near future.
>
> If you must use Android Studio, check out this thread on the forums.
>
> Alternatively you can use Intellij IDEA with libgdx, potentially with
>   Maven.

Comment: Thanks. I saw it yesterday.

Comment: I've managed to make it work (desktop and android modules in Android Studio) based on this http://imgur.com/a/IBFIV

Answer (score 5):

Creating games in gdx works perfectly fine in Android Studio.  The best way to create a project for Android Studio is through gdx-setup.  Please go to the following article

http://www.todroid.com/android-gdx-game-creation-part-i-setting-up-up-android-studio-for-creating-games/

It explains my experience in using the gdx-setup application, how to run it on the PC platform and steps for importing the gradle project and building a project in gradle.

When you have finished the article, hopefully you will have a fully working sample game template in which you can start building your game.

Comment: It's good to see a response that shows how easy it is now that LibGDX supports Gradle !  (although you may want to clarify that, because the other responses were written before this was possible)

Comment: I follow the instructions and all works good. But when I want to use Pixmap in the html project, I expect that the IDE will point to the Pixmap implemented in the gwt-backend. The project does not compile! Any help. (FYI, in eclipse this issue not arrised)

Answer (score 4):

I tried to use a similiar method used for native libraries for now.

Last night, I was able to run examples; as a scratch project in Android Studio and wrote a quick guideline

Hope it helps you as well, but I am still learning so sorry in advance for any missing info or mistakes ;)

Here's the link.. http://bgnstudio.wordpress.com

> I tried to use this way in detail:

create a new project in Android Studio.

From the libgdx nightly build, get;

```
Libgdx.so files  within the armeabi/armeabi-v7a folders as needed.
Gdx.jar and gdx-source.jar
Gdx-backend-android.jar
```

Create lib  and libs directories under project folder .

Copy armeabi* folders , gdx.jar and gdx-source.jar files under the “lib” directory.

Also copy the gdx-backend-android.jar into the “libs” directory.

*

> In project tree;  add gdx.jar and gdx-backend-android.jar as library.
>
> In  library settings, add gdx-source.jar under gdx.jar;  Then open
>   module settings and add these  libraries as dependencies.  And check
>   them for compile.

Archive the armeabi folders  together with parent directory to zip files  and rename extension from zip to jar.

> ```
> armeabi.jar                 : “/lib/armeabi/libgdx.so”
>
> armeabi-v7a.jar         :“/lib/armeabi-v7a/libgdx.so”
> ```

And move these jar files under “libs” directory.

Final apperance of the folders will be like this:

> ```
> |-lib
>
> |---gdx.jar
>
> |---gdx-sorces.jar  (added  as source library of gdx.jar in library settings)
>
> |-libs
>
> |--- armeabi.jar
>
> |--- armeabi-v7a.jar
>
> |--- gdx-backend-android.jar
> ```

Now modify build.gradle file as well:

> ```
> dependencies {
>
> compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:+'
>
> compile files('lib/gdx.jar')
>
> compile files('libs/gdx-backend-android.jar')
>
> compile fileTree(dir: 'libs' , include:'*.jar')
>
> }
> ```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried [IntelliJ 13](http://blogs.jetbrains.com/idea/2013/05/intellij-idea-13-early-preview-is-out/)? [Download it here](http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/IDEADEV/IDEA+13+EAP) . This new version covers most of the function of Android Studio, but still it can make Java Project. Take a look at [this article](http://blog.jetbrains.com/blog/2013/05/15/intellij-idea-is-the-base-for-android-studio-the-new-ide-for-android-developers/)

> This EAP build includes all of the new features of Android Studio except for the new project wizard and the AppEngine cloud endpoints integration. These latter features will also appear in our EAP builds in the coming weeks.

Answer (score 0):

take a look at libdgx documentation:
https://code.google.com/p/libgdx/wiki/IntelliJIDEALibgdx

Comment: Even though Android Studio is based on InteliJ , this is not the same.Can you create a working libGDX project using this guide ? Because I can't.

Answer (score 0):

mark the Advanced->IDEA checkbox at libgdx project setup tool, create the project and import it from android studio(you will need add the assets folder to desktop launcher or maybe somethings like this), it works for me.